# How to make multiple similar tests in a loop inside a JUnit-test method (with custom objects)?

Tags: java, junit

I want to create a for-loop inside a test method, so that it would tell me what specific test it didn't pass. The mentioned method is such:

```
@Test
void parse0() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = reader(writeFile(i));
            try {
                Parser parser = new Parser();
                Tree parsed = parser.parse(bufferedReader);
                assertEquals(parsed, answers[i]);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't really matter what Parser does here as I only want to check on what iteration did the test fail and what specific trees were checked. The Tree implementation is such:

```
public class Tree {
    String node;
    List<Tree> children;

    public Tree(String node) {
        this.node = node;
        children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Tree(String node, List<Tree> children) {
        this.node = node;
        this.children = children;
    }

    public void add(Tree node) {
        children.add(node);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!(obj instanceof Tree tree)) {
            return false;
        }

        return recursiveEquals(this, tree);
    }

    private boolean recursiveEquals(Tree tree1, Tree tree2) {
        boolean ans = true;
        if (tree1 == null && tree2 == null) {
            return true;
        } else if (tree1 == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (tree2 == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (tree1.children.size() != tree2.children.size()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!tree1.node.equals(tree2.node)) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tree1.children.size(); i++) {
            ans &= recursiveEquals(tree1.children.get(i), tree2.children.get(i));
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

I made a lot of copies with the same test, but this is obviously a bad idea that generates lots of copy-paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assertEquals` accepts a third argument as a message.

See: https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.8/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)

So just add a message with the id of your file or whatever helps to identify your test case.

```java
assertEquals("Test "+i+" failed", parsed, answers[i]);
```